# adding objects programmatically to powerpoint slides forcing all objects animation

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I am adding some objects to a PowerPoint slide on the fly along with some animations. Problem is when I add any object after adding the first object then both the previously added object along with current object comes with animation. How do I make my previously added object stay as it is and only the new one come with animation, here is some code that I am using,

```
private void AddShapeToSlide(int left, int top, int width, int height)
{
    Slide slide = GetCurrentSlide();
    Shape shape = slide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, left, top, width, height);
    ApplyAnimation(slide, shape);
    shape.ZOrder(MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringToFront);
    _presentation.SlideShowWindow.Activate();
}

private void ApplyAnimation(Slide slide, Shape shape)
{
    shape.AnimationSettings.AdvanceMode = PpAdvanceMode.ppAdvanceOnTime;
    shape.AnimationSettings.AdvanceTime = 0;
    shape.AnimationSettings.Animate = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    shape.AnimationSettings.EntryEffect = GetPowerPointTransition();

    Effect effect = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.FindFirstAnimationFor(shape);
    if (effect != null && shape.AnimationSettings.EntryEffect != PpEntryEffect.ppEffectNone)
    {
         effect.Timing.Duration = 5;
    }
}
```

Any help or idea is of great value. Thanks In Advance.